# gcloud - 500 internal server error with angular 1 + node js

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-build

I am getting following error logs -

```
2019-05-15 11:51:20 default[20190515t114916]  { [Error: ENOENT: no such file or
directory, stat '/srv/client/dist/client/index.html']
2019-05-15 11:51:20 default[20190515t114916]    errno: -2,
2019-05-15 11:51:20 default[20190515t114916]    code: 'ENOENT',
2019-05-15 11:51:20 default[20190515t114916]    syscall: 'stat',
2019-05-15 11:51:20 default[20190515t114916]    path: '/srv/client/dist/client/i
ndex.html',
```

while deploying an app built in Angular (version 1) and node js (version 10)

my app folder structure is as follows, in **client** folder I have angular js codes and in **server** folder I have node js -

[image]

**app.yaml** file looks like

```
runtime: nodejs10
```

and cloudbuild.yaml file is as -

```
steps:
  #install
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm'
    args: ['install']

   #deploy
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
    args: ['app', 'deploy']
```

I am newbie in google cloud and not sure how to configure yaml files. Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add `ng build` after the `install` step, and append something like this
in app.yaml

```
- url: /
  static_files: dist/index.html
  upload: dist/index.html
- url: /
  static_dir: dist
```

the `dist` folder will be created by `ng build`

Comment: Cool, glad to hear that